# How to `echo` a variable declared / initialized in another function in a shell script?

Tags: bash

Run this in Ubuntu 14.04.1:

```
./script.sh MyVM take
```

*Why does the `echo` line in the function `list_snapshot` work (it prints the value of those 3 variables) but the `echo` line in `take_snapshot` can't print the value of the variable `$output` and `$old_snapshot_name` but only print the value of `$machine_name`?*

*Note that the script works when I run `./script.sh MyVM take`, it does delete the old snapshot and create a new snapshot.*

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ ! "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <vmname> list|take"
    exit 1
else
    machine_name=$1
fi

list_snapshot () {
    output=$(VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" list)
    count=$(echo "$output" | grep -c 'UUID')

    echo "Machine '$machine_name' has '$count' snapshots: \n '$output'"
    return "$count"
}


take_snapshot () {
    echo "$output"
    while (list_snapshot; [ $? -gt 3 ])  
    do
        old_snapshot_name=$(echo "$output" | grep -o 'UUID: (.{36})' | head -1)
        echo "Deleting old snapshot '$old_snapshot_name' for machine '$machine_name'..."

        VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" delete "$old_snapshot_name"

    done

    current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
    snapshot_name=$machine_name.$current_time

    echo "Taking new snapshot '$snapshot_name' for machine '$machine_name'..."
    VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" take "$snapshot_name" --live 
}

case "$2" in
  list)
    list_snapshot
    ;;
  take)
    take_snapshot
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 <vmname> list|take"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Output without `-x` ：`./snapshotVM.sh RancherOS-tools take`

```
Machine 'RancherOS-tools' has '4' snapshots: 
 '   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.25.12 (UUID: 7afef8ee-1915-4494-9634-add82e1a613f)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.25.40 (UUID: 79a53543-377e-4a74-80ca-751883a7787b)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
            Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051) *'
Deleting old snapshot '' for machine 'RancherOS-tools'...
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Machine 'RancherOS-tools' has '3' snapshots: 
 '   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.25.40 (UUID: 79a53543-377e-4a74-80ca-751883a7787b)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051) *'
Taking new snapshot 'RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20' for machine 'RancherOS-tools'...
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Snapshot taken. UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe
```

Output with `-x` ：`./snapshotVM.sh RancherOS-tools take`

```
dy@dy:~$ ./snapshotVM.sh RancherOS-tools take
+ [ ! RancherOS-tools ]
+ machine_name=RancherOS-tools
+ take_snapshot
+ echo 

+ list_snapshot
+ VBoxManage snapshot RancherOS-tools list
+ output=   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.25.40 (UUID: 79a53543-377e-4a74-80ca-751883a7787b)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
            Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *
+ echo    Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.25.40 (UUID: 79a53543-377e-4a74-80ca-751883a7787b)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
            Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *
+ grep -c UUID
+ count=4
+ echo Machine 'RancherOS-tools' has '4' snapshots: \n '   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.25.40 (UUID: 79a53543-377e-4a74-80ca-751883a7787b)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
            Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *'
Machine 'RancherOS-tools' has '4' snapshots: 
 '   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.25.40 (UUID: 79a53543-377e-4a74-80ca-751883a7787b)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
            Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *'
+ return 4
+ [ 4 -gt 3 ]
+ echo 
+ head -1
+ grep -o UUID: (.{36})
+ old_snapshot_name=
+ echo Deleting old snapshot '' for machine 'RancherOS-tools'...
Deleting old snapshot '' for machine 'RancherOS-tools'...
+ VBoxManage snapshot RancherOS-tools delete 
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
+ list_snapshot
+ VBoxManage snapshot RancherOS-tools list
+ output=   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *
+ echo    Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *
+ grep -c UUID
+ count=3
+ echo Machine 'RancherOS-tools' has '3' snapshots: \n '   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *'
Machine 'RancherOS-tools' has '3' snapshots: 
 '   Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.32.10 (UUID: 25a942fe-2d0a-4290-a98e-7d16ec4c60bd)
      Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.34.58 (UUID: 02af926b-396c-4ce6-bfb3-5e953de5a051)
         Name: RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.35.20 (UUID: 5195881b-113b-448a-81e3-98a121c8fbfe) *'
+ return 3
+ [ 3 -gt 3 ]
+ date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
+ current_time=2015.11.03-11.37.46
+ snapshot_name=RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.37.46
+ echo Taking new snapshot 'RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.37.46' for machine 'RancherOS-tools'...
Taking new snapshot 'RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.37.46' for machine 'RancherOS-tools'...
+ VBoxManage snapshot RancherOS-tools take RancherOS-tools.2015.11.03-11.37.46 --live
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Snapshot taken. UUID: 0e11c8d0-130c-4508-a2be-8692fc9316bd
```

**Update: looks like I meet some variable scope problem, after redesign my code, remove while loop, now it works**

```
#! /bin/sh

# usage: 
# $0 <vmname> list : list all snapshot
# $0 <vmname> take : delete old snapshot name startwith "Backup" and leave 3 "Backup" snapshot

#set -x

if [ ! "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <vmname> list|take"
    exit 1
else
    machine_name=$1
fi

list_snapshot () {
    output=$(VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" list)
    count=$(echo "$output" | grep -c 'UUID')

    echo "Machine $machine_name has $count snapshots: "
    echo "$output"
}


take_snapshot () {
    output=$(VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" list)
    count=$(echo "$output" | grep -c 'Backup')

    echo "Machine $machine_name has $count snapshots: "
    echo "$output"

    if [ "$count" -ge 3 ]; then
        old_snapshots_uuid=$(echo "$output" | grep "Backup" | grep -Eo 'UUID: .{36}' | cut -c 7-42 | head -$((count-2)))

        for u in $old_snapshots_uuid; do
          echo "Deleting old snapshot $u for machine $machine_name..."
          VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" delete "$u"
        done    
    fi

    current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
    snapshot_name="Backup".$machine_name.$current_time

    echo "Taking new snapshot $snapshot_name for machine $machine_name..."
    VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" take "$snapshot_name"     
}

case "$2" in
  list)
    list_snapshot
    ;;
  take)
    take_snapshot
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 <vmname> list|take"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Also, does `echo "$output"` in `take_snapshot ()` work?

Comment: @kos No, not work, I have to copy `output=$(VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" list)` in `list_snapshot` into `take_snapshot` then it work , don't know why can't just using this variable from `list_snapshot`

Comment: Because it's out of `take_snapshot`'s scope; functions can only see their local variables and global variables, not other function's variables. You should remove `output=$(VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" list)` from `list_snapshot` and initialize it outside of any function if you want all functions to be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't; variables declared / initialized in a function are only visible in that function's scope.

Also in your specific case, if you run `./script.sh MyVM take`, `list_snapshot()` is not even run; how is `output` supposed to be declared / initialized (and how is `old_snapshot_name` supposed to be declared / initialized, since its declaration / initialization relies on `output`, which has not been declared / initialized?)

To make `output` visible to all the functions and regardless of which functions are actually run, move its declaration / initialization outside of `list_snapshot()`, for example after `take_snapshot()`'s definition:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh

if [ ! "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <vmname> list|take"
    exit 1
else
    machine_name=$1
fi

list_snapshot () {
    count=$(echo "$output" | grep -c 'UUID')

    echo "Machine '$machine_name' has '$count' snapshots: \n '$output'"
    return "$count"
}


take_snapshot () {
    echo "$output"
    while (list_snapshot; [ $? -gt 3 ])  
    do
        old_snapshot_name=$(echo "$output" | grep -o 'UUID: (.{36})' | head -1)
        echo "Deleting old snapshot '$old_snapshot_name' for machine '$machine_name'..."

        VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" delete "$old_snapshot_name"

    done

    current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
    snapshot_name=$machine_name.$current_time

    echo "Taking new snapshot '$snapshot_name' for machine '$machine_name'..."
    VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" take "$snapshot_name" --live 
}

output=$(VBoxManage snapshot "$machine_name" list)

case "$2" in
  list)
    list_snapshot
    ;;
  take)
    take_snapshot
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 <vmname> list|take"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you,  looks like I meet some variable scope problem, , after redesign my code, remove while loop, now it works

Comment: If the answer has helped you, accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer. **;)**